# What is the best way to create a form letter in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, forms

In MS Word 2003 I could right-click and pick a format, and a toolbar came up that would allow me to highlight certain areas to allow people to type in a letter and tab through, and would also allow me to lock certain parts that I did not want changed in our form letters.

What is the best way to create a form letter in Word 2007?

Answer (score 1):

It took me about 15 seconds to find tutorials and examples on create form letters in Word 2007.

https://www.google.com/search?q=word+2007+form+letters

Based upon your specific question, this might help:

http://www.hartnell.edu/faculty/frc/guides/fillabelformword.pdf

Google is your friend...